Using Pyarrow, how do you group by a value, then select the top K largest values in that group?
I'm looking group by a PyArrow column, then within each of those groups select the top K values without using Pandas. For example, given this dataset:



id
score




1
0


1
1


1
2


1
3


1
4


2
5


2
6


2
7


2
8


2
9



with K = 2
I would like to group by id, then select the top 2 scores for that ID, in order to receive



id
score




1
4


1
3


2
9


2
8



I have tried the following:
df = pa.table([
    pa.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), 
    pa.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
], names=["id", "score"])

df.group_by("id").aggregate([("score", "list")])

And then I get stuck here. I've tried to piece together pc.list_flatten and pc.list_parent_indices, but I'm new to PyArrow and I don't think I'm thinking through this correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

It's possible, but it's not easy.
Basically:

sort the table so score is descending (and optionally id is ascending).
group by / aggregate in list, disabling threads to preserve the order
take the first 2 elements of the list
"explode" the list with a mix of list_parent_indices and list_flatten

import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.compute as pc

df = pa.table(
    [
        pa.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]),
        pa.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
    ],
    names=["id", "score"],
)

df = (
    df.sort_by([("id", "ascending"), ("score", "descending")])
    .group_by("id", use_threads=False)
    .aggregate([("score", "list")])
)

top_2 = pc.list_slice(df["score_list"], start=0, stop=2)

df = pa.Table.from_arrays(
    [df["id"].take(pc.list_parent_indices(top_2)), pc.list_flatten(top_2)],
    names=["id", "score"],
)





id
score




1
4


1
3


2
9


2
8




Thanks this works great.
I'm wondering if grouping then sorting within the groups is possible? I'm using this with a pretty large dataset, and can't help but think sorting smaller groups could be faster than sorting the entire dataset.
